# Select distinct value and bring only the latest one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores different statuses of each transaction. Each transaction can have multiple statuses (pending, rejected, aproved, etc).

I need to build a query that brings only the last status of each transaction.

The definition for the table that stores the statuses is:

```
[dbo].[Cuotas_Estado]
ID int (PK)
IdCuota int          (references table dbo.Cuotas - FK)
IdEstado int         (references table dbo.Estados - FK)
```

Here's the architecture for the 3 tables:

[image: arch]

When running a simple SELECT statement on table dbo.Cuotas_Estado you'll get:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [dbo].[Cuotas_Estado] [E]
```

[image: sel1]

But the result I need is:

```
IdCuota    | IdEstado
2          | 1
3          | 2
9          | 3
10         | 3
11         | 4
```

I'm running the following select statement:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT([E].[IdEstado]),
    [E].[IdCuota]
FROM [dbo].[Cuotas_Estado] [E]
ORDER BY
    [E].[IdCuota] ASC;
```

This will bring this result:

[image]

So, as you can see, it's bringing a double value to entry 9 and entry 11, I need the query to bring only the latest IdEstado column (3 in the entry 9 and 4 in the entry 11).

Comment: Do a GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: If you only need those two columns then won't a simple `group by` and `max()` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this?

```
with cte as (
    select IdEstado,IdCuota,
           row_number() over(partition by IdCuota order by fecha desc) as RowNum
        from [dbo].[Cuotas_Estado]
)
select IdEstado,IdCuota
    from cte
    where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Worked just as expected! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM [dbo].[Cuotas_Estado] e
WHERE e.IdEstado = (SELECT MAX(e2.IdEstado)
                    FROM [dbo].[Cuotas_Estado] e2
                    WHERE e2.IdCuota = e.IdCuota
                   );
```

With an index on `Cuotas_Estado(IdCuota, IdEstado)` this is probably the most efficient method.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution. The thing with this one is that it brings the top IdEstado by number, and it should by the latest one inserted in the table.